# Trying to feed the results from a subquery as a string into the main query

Tags: sql, hive, presto

```
 select distinct userid,fingerprint as deviceid
   from hive.fraud_stage.fingerprint_snapshot
   where entity_type = 'deviceid'
   and fingerprint in (select distinct userid,fingerprint as deviceid
   from hive.fraud_stage.fingerprint_snapshot
   where entity_type = 'deviceid'
   and userid in 
   (
   '10005659'
))
```

I am trying to feed the results from a subquery as a string into the main query. The results given by the subquery will be a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Eric!

Comment: What is the problem with the query?

Comment: Hi @forpas, it is throwing me the following error:

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 cannot recognize input near 'where' 'oa' '.' in from source

Comment: remove the , before where

Comment: @forpas How silly of me! Thanks so much! I have another query with which i need some help. May i?

Comment: If it's a different query then since this problem was just a typo, delete this question and post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery differs from the main query only in 1 condition: `and userid in = '10005659'`.
The IN clause of course would throw an error because the subquery returns 2 columns instead of 1.
I think this is enough:

```
select distinct userid, fingerprint as deviceid
from hive.fraud_stage.fingerprint_snapshot
where entity_type = 'deviceid'
and userid = '10005659'
```

Comment: I dont think this will suffice because i am trying to use the results of "deviceid" to be fed to "fingerprint". So ultimately i will have to run 2 queries instead of one.

Comment: deviceid is the alias fingerprint. The main query and the subquery you wrote are exactly the same with the difference of the condition `userid = '10005659'`